# mount(2): Stale file handle NFS after update server to Debian 8

Tags: centos7, xfs, nfs4

I've several server that mounting NFS on remote backups server

Everything worked until I did an update on the NFS server to Debian Jessie.

Now **some** machines work and others not work.

Try several docs over internet about problem and i do not get a solution

```
mount -t nfs -vv stor01.KIKO.net:/srv/storage/backup/srv107/backupremote /backupremote2/
final mount options: '(null)'
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Jun 23 15:22:54 2016
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=195.154.xx.xx,clientaddr=5.135.xx.xx'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Stale file handle
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=195.154.xx.xx,clientaddr=5.135.xx.xx'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Stale file handle
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=195.154.xx.xxx,clientaddr=5.135.xx.xx'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Stale file handle
```

Server

```
/etc/exports
/srv/storage/backup/srv105    176.31.XX.xx(sync,no_root_squash,rw,nohide)  # WORK FINE
/srv/storage/backup/srv107    5.135.XX.xx(sync,no_root_squash,rw,nohide)  # NOT WORK
```

**Two clients** has a same Centos 7 version.

Try reboot server and clients... nothing... some clients work, others no.

SOLVED

Problem it's a not trivial question. I update my systems to XFS and put long disk (20TB)

Find this question [Big XFS filesystem NFS export mount fails with stale nfs handle](http://blog.erben.sk/2015/01/25/xfs-filesystem-nfs-export-mount-fails-with-stale-nfs-handle/) and read, [XFS & Inode64](https://hpc.uni.lu/blog/2014/xfs-and-inode64/) for I understand concept.

After this, remove disk, and reformat with older ext4 system ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem it's a not trivial question. I update my systems to XFS and put long disk (20TB)

Find this question Big XFS filesystem NFS export mount fails with stale nfs handle and read, XFS & Inode64 for I understand concept.

After this, remove disk, and reformat with older ext4 system ;-)